# How to show Spinner view below spinner widget

Tags: android

Hi all i wanted show spinner of small size list view and i wanted show it below the spinner widget. Default spinner takes full screen I wanted to re size it.thanks

Comment: perhaps you should use **AutoCompleteTextView**. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html

Answer (score 7):

For all api use this

First set android:spinnerMode="dropdown"

```
android:dropDownVerticalOffset="40dp"
```

here offset may vary according to height of spinner

Comment: I tried this attribute, works on my OP6, but doesn't work on some smartphones. Like Samsung

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Spinner's spinnerMode property, set this property to `dropdown`.

```
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
```

Comment: No, it is just stating the type of mode. It can be dialog as well by using this attribute. It is nothing about the position of dropdown!